# Flutter: SvgPicture/png Image gets pixelated

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-image

Any solution to fix the pixelated issue on flutter? Here is my code.

`Code`

```
Image.asset(
            'assets/logo.png',
          ),
```

```
SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/logo.svg',
          ),
```

Even i tried to solve it with `filterQuality` but i didn't find this as a solution.

filterQuality: FilterQuality.medium,

filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,

Comment: Some versions of flutter have an issue with rendering the images properly on web. I recommend you to update your flutter to the latest version.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What is your problem? Please describe in detail your problem. If necessary, please add illustrations

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Subash Thank you for reaching out.
I have updated the flutter to the latest version.
But image on the web gets pixelated.

Comment: @TrầnVănHiếu 
 I have used an image with the extension of .svg /.png but while rendering on the web it is getting pixelated.

here is the Code

 SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/logo.svg',
          ),
Image.asset(
            'assets/logo.png',
          ),

Also tried using 
filterQuality: FilterQuality.medium,

filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,

but still I am facing the issue.

Comment: @SabinSimkhada any error on the console? Also include a screenshot of the rendered image if possible.

Answer (score 0):

-- in this case you can applay height and width for set pixel.

-->

```
 SvgPicture.asset(
  'asserts://image.png', /// add your image path.
  width: 200, // set width
  height: 200, // set height
),
```